# To get select2 angular only arrow click event

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

Am using select2 dropdown in angular.I have to get dropdown arrow click event, not the whole select box event. Is this possible? Based on arrow arrow click event i have to call another function.

Comment: Please add which package you are using for dropdown?

Comment: angular-select2.js